# How to change zoom size in differents pages using Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, zooming

I use google maps and zoom to localization my points.

I use JS file to all scripts with Google Maps and *I want to change for one page (results) zoom from 13 to 15*. what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I found in url "z=21" , but I can't find that in my project. It's looking how defauilt max zoom for google.